# MANOVA Repeated Measures

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons, manova

I hope somebody can help me with my confusion.

My dependent variables are: emotions, interest, and attitude change, while independent variable is type of message: a) self-appraisal message b) family-appraisal message, c) combination of a) and b)

There is also a control message.

One of my hypotheses is: There will be a statistically significant difference on subject`s emotional, interest, and attitude change response when self-appraisal message is presented.

After conducting MANOVA, I found a significant effect, while univariate ANOVAs found significant effect for emotions and attitude change. Since interest was non-significant, does this mean that my hypothesis was not supported? I am not sure whether my  hypotheses would be correct only if all DV`s were significant or?

Thank you!!

Comment: No. If you just write down the null hypothesis of the MANOVA you'll get it. The null is emotions doesn't change AND interest doesn't change AND attitude doesn't change. So the opposite of that is...

Comment: @AdamO But since interest did stay the same, does that mean that i would write that my hypothesis was not fully supported or? Not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: The null hypothesis is: emotions doesn't change AND interest doesn't change AND attitude doesn't change. Therefore the alternative is: emotions change OR interest changes OR attitude changes.